# Program failed in executing step by step

Tags: c

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int binaryToDecimal(long binarynum){
    int decimalnum = 0, temp = 0, remainder;
    while(binarynum!=0){
        remainder = binarynum % 10;
        remainder = binarynum / 10;
        decimalnum = decimalnum+remainder*pow(2,temp);
        temp++;
    }
    return decimalnum;
}
long decimalToBinary(int n){
    int remainder;
    long binary = 0,i = 1;
    while(n != 0){
        remainder = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        binary = binary + (remainder*i);
        i = i*10;
    }
    return binary;
}
int main(){
    int quotient, rem,decimalnum1,decimalnum2;
    long binarynum1, binarynum2;

    printf("Enter dividend binary number::");
    scanf("%ld",&binarynum1);

    printf("Enter divisor binary number::");
    scanf("%ld",&binarynum2);
    /// execution stops from here.
    decimalnum1 = binaryToDecimal(binarynum1);
    decimalnum2 = binaryToDecimal(binarynum2);
    quotient = decimalnum1/decimalnum2;
    rem = decimalnum1%decimalnum2;
    printf("Quotient  is: %ld",decimalToBinary(quotient));
    printf("Remainder is: %ld",decimalToBinary(rem));
    getch();
}
```

I was working  with the program to perform division between binary numbers. But 
the program execution stops after 6th statement. I tried to change the variable types but still having problem. 
Output of the program execution is here.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p04h.png)

Comment: What do you mean? What steps did you use to determine that the *program execution stops*? That's almost certainly not what it's actually doing.

Comment: You mean when you debug? Show us how do you compile it. You may need to add debug flags to the compiler.

Comment: At which statement in the source you show did the program stop? Can you please mark it out with e.g. a comment? And on that line, what was the values of all involved variables?

Comment: So the program doesn't really "stop", it just seems to never end? Well take a look at [the answer from SenselessCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48597730/440558) for a reason about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite loop problem in your `binaryToDecimal` function.

```
int binaryToDecimal(long binarynum){
    int decimalnum = 0, temp = 0, remainder;
    while(binarynum!=0){
        remainder = binarynum % 10;
        remainder = binarynum / 10;
        decimalnum = decimalnum+remainder*pow(2,temp);
        temp++;
    }
    return decimalnum;
}
```

Where's the part that changes `binarynum` variable? See, it never changes in the loop so it can't ever be 0. Your loop runs forever.

Comment: Thank you it was just a small error that i can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Your binaryToDecimal function runs in infinite loop. Try the function below instead.

```
int binaryToDecimal(long n)
{
    int decimalNumber = 0, i = 0, remainder;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        remainder = n%10;
        n /= 10;
        decimalNumber += remainder*pow(2,i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimalNumber;
}
```